# Looking for some Android layout advice

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have an issue where I need to add several (>20) to a layout at run time and the buttons can be 2 different widths and 2 different heights.  I dont know the exact size of these buttons at design time as the minimum size will be determined by the device screen.  So I thought I would use Linear Layout and use weights to manage the size of the buttons but you can only layout in one direction at a time, where I need the buttons to be able to double their size in either direction see below ascii art.  I also looked at relative layout but I would need to specify the size of the buttons at design time which I don't as each user could have different layouts based on which buttons they want to emphasise.

```
<code>
 +--------+   
 |        | single size button
 |        |   
 +--------+

 +--------+--------+
 |                 | double width single height
 |                 |
 +--------+--------+

 +--------+
 |        |
 |        | double height single width
 +        +
 |        |
 |        |
 +--------+

 +--------+--------+
 |                 |
 |                 | double height double width
 +                 +
 |                 |
 |                 |
 +--------+--------+
</code>
```

With that in mind this is a possible layout

```
<code>
+--------+ +--------+ +--------+--------+ +--------+  
|        | |        | |                 | |        |
|        | |        | |                 | |        |
+--------+ +--------+ +--------+--------+ +        + 
+--------+ +--------+-+--------+          |        |    
|        | |                   |          |        |   
|        | |                   |          |        |
+--------+ +-------------------+          +--------+  

</code>
```

So I can't determine a way of building a layout that is this flexible and was wondering if you could tell me if building this layout can only be done in code rather than a more efficient and reusable xml based layout?

Regards
Damien

Comment: Since API Level **14**, you can use the GridLayout: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html. Or you can use the TableLayout http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html since API Level **1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with [StaggeredGridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html) from new Lollipop API. These classes are available in support library.

They let to make something like this,
it supports horizontal and vertical scroll, had be used like ListView and It can had be filled dynamically.

[image]

[Or use any libraries, that you can find by key word - twowayview](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/)